# How can I suppress the creation of the hs_err_pid file?

Tags: java, java-6, hs-err

We are running a java application under java 1.6.0_13. When it crashes it creates the normal hs_err_pid file. I don't want this file created even if the application crashes. Is there a way on the java command line to suppress this?
I am familiar with -XX:ErrorFile option. If I set this to an empty string will that suppress it?

Comment: You could probably test it out by causing a JVM crash via JNI (just create a little C library that segfaults) or something similar.  Feels kind of gross considering suppressing log output for such a critical failure as a JVM crash though.

Comment: If using Linux you can use the command `kill` to send a `SIGSEGV` signal to test your fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using a Unix/Linux system, try setting `-XX:ErrorFile` to `/dev/null` (or, if you are using Windows, try `NUL`).

Comment: in which config file do I have to set -XX:ErrorFile to /dev/null in linux ?

Comment: @MartinVegter I guess its JVM argument

Answer (score 5):

With Oracle HotSpot (since `6b21`) and OpenJDK, the `-XX:+SuppressFatalErrorMessage` option should be used for preventing creation of the `hs_err_pid` file.

Nowadays, using `-XX:ErrorFile=/dev/null` will actually not work as expected, since if the file path specified to `ErrorFile` exists, the JVM will not attempt to overwrite it and will fall back to the default `hs_err_pid` location (there's no special case handling for `/dev/null`).

For more details, see also:

- [Why java ignored the option “-XX:ErrorFile=/dev/null”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782726/why-java-ignored-option-xxerrorfile-dev-null)
- [Oracle ticket, JDK-6194668](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6194668): Add java runtime flag `SuppressFatalErrorMessage` to skip all error handling logic on fatal error
- [OpenJDK ticket, JDK-8189672](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189672): `-XX:ErrorFile` doesn't work.