# How to clear hs_err_pid log file in home directory

Tags: java, linux

I have lots of log file in my home directory:

```
hs_err_pid2326.log
hs_err_pid2416.log
```

I believe it is a java error log file, how to remove it and stop creating them?

Java version:

```
[kelvin@localhost ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode
```

Comment: Have you found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149039/how-can-i-suppress-the-creation-of-the-hs-err-pid-file yet?

Comment: Suppressing creation of jvm crash logs is a terrible idea. These logs are created when the equivalent of the blue screen of death occurs on the jvm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are created if and when the JVM crashes; they're analogous to a `core` file, but contain a lot of Java-specific information. They're just text files, and you can delete them like you would any other files:

```
$ rm ~/hs_err_pid*.log
```

You can stop creating them by no longer crashing the JVM. Normally, such crashes are rare. Look at the files themselves in a text editor and they will contain some info about their origins.

Comment: They are mostly from the IDE I used, eclipse and phpstorm. But most of them is eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

These are Java crash (core) dump log files. Identify which Java process creates them by tracing and monitoring the PID.

Answer (score 2):

Have a shutdown script to delete these files.

With `systemd`, create a script deleting those files, e.g. `/home/user/cleanJavaLogs.bash`:

```
    rm /home/user/hs_err_pid*
```

Then create a service descriptor file `/etc/systemd/system/clearJavaLogs.service` containing:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Clear Javascript "hs_err_pidnnnn.log" files on shutdown
    DefaultDependencies=no
    Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/home/user/cleanJavaLogs.bash

    [Install]
    WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

and activate the service:

```
    systemctl enable clearJavaLogs.service
```