# why java ignored option "-XX:ErrorFile=/dev/null"

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I want to prevent JVM generating crash log files, so my startup script looks like this

```
java -XX:ErrorFile=/dev/null MyClass
```

but when a jvm crash occurs, the log file 'hs_err_pidXXXXX.log' is still generated in current working directory. why ?

OS:  ubuntu 18.04, java version: oracle java 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file specified to `-XX:ErrorFile` exists, or can't be opened, then the JVM falls back to the default `hs_err_pid` error file path. Since `/dev/null` probably exists, that could explain this behaviour.

I've browsed the OpenJDK JVM source code, corresponding to Oracle's HotSpot, and there doesn't seem to be any special handling of `/dev/null` in the error reporting code in this respect.

For more details and comments from JVM maintainers, see this OpenJDK bug report:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189672

Comment: Perfectly explained. I'd only add a couple options to work around that. `-XX:+SuppressFatalErrorMessage` disables error reporting altogether. It's also possible to remove the log file right after creation: `-XX:OnError="rm hs_err_pid%p.log"`